# Angular 2+: Testing form with mat-slide-toggle - change event won't fire

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am not sure why the the change event isn't firing and therefore not triggering the function I registered for the change event.

I know this works when I run it, but I can't get it in the spec.

Here is a demo of what I am talking about... As you can see from the logs, the `toggle` never gets called:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test-utmbmy?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts

Roughly, this is my code here...

component.html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="useDefault" (change)="toggle($event)"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

component.ts:

```
...
toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  console.log('Toggle fired');
  this.useDefault = event.checked;
}
```

In my spec.ts:

```
it('should trigger toggle...', () => {
  const componentDebug = fixture.debugElement;
  const slider: MatSlideToggle = 
     componentDebug.query(By.css('form mat-slide-toggle')).componentInstance;

  console.log('before ' + slider.checked);
  slider.toggle();

  fixture.detectChanges();

  console.log('after ' + slider.checked);
  console.log('useDefault ' + component.useDefault);
});
```

The `after` logging does print out `slider.checked` to be the opposite value from `before`. However, the `component.useDefault` stays the same and the logging statement in the `toggle` function is never called, which means it never triggered it.

Why is this going on and how do I fix this?

I've tried placing the whole thing into `fakeAsync`, using `tick`, placing the 'after' code into `fixture.whenStable()` and `fixture.whenRenderingDone()`.

I have a `NoopAnimationsModule` in the `TestBed`'s `import`.

Comment: What is the `useDefault`? Is something from the `mat-slide-toggle`? Is a directive you created?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Ok, I updated my question code. `useDefault` was just a typo, it was supposed to be `[checked]="useDefault"`. However, I modified your component a bit to be more in line with what I have, i.e., start out with `useDefault = true`. I only added some logging statements. Now, for reasons I can't understand, the `toggle` log isn't showing up anymore:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test-utmbmy?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts

Comment: Try firing the change event directly: `componentDebug.query(By.css('mat-slide-toggle')).nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` You will probably have to mock the MatSlideToggleChange object somhow as well.

Answer (score 30):

When using third-party components, you should trust them to handle the event. However, you could trigger the event, using the [triggereventhandler](https://angular.io/guide/testing#triggereventhandler) while you [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) the method you want to be called.

## Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `
        <mat-slide-toggle
            [checked]="useDefault" (change)="toggle($event)"
        ></mat-slide-toggle>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
    public useDefault = false;

    public toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
        console.log('toggle', event.checked);
        this.useDefault = event.checked;
    }
}
```

## Test

```
it('should call change method on slide change', () => {
    const componentDebug = fixture.debugElement;
    const slider = componentDebug.query(By.directive(MatSlideToggle));
    spyOn(component, 'toggle'); // set your spy

    slider.triggerEventHandler('change', null); // triggerEventHandler

    expect(component.toggle).toHaveBeenCalled(); // event has been called
});
```

See the test passing on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test-spy-trigger-event?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts

Comment: I am not sure you are correct in your point of trusting 3rd party components to handle the event.... I can trust them that they will emit the event, but I need to test that my bindings in the template are correct. So, calling my bound function directly will certainly test that function. However, say someone later comes along and edits the template of my components and erases the `(change)="onToggle()"`. The tests will still pass because I am testing `onToggle` directly, but the app won't work because the event binding is now missing. I will have to post my solution soon...

Comment: In short, the solution (for now) was to do `const slider: HtmlElement = 
     componentDebug.query(By.css('form mat-slide-toggle input')).nativeElement;` and then do `slider.click()`. That actually makes the `MatSlideToggle` emit the `change` event. I actually think it's a bug in `MatSlideToggle` component. Its `toggle()` function flips the `this.checked = !this.checked` but does NOT emit a change event. I think that's a bug. It should.

Comment: @user1902183, actually if you erase the `(change)="onToggle()"` your test will fail. (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test-spy-trigger-event-not-called). IMO, you should have a unit test for the logic inside toggle and another one to call on event change (like the example)

Comment: Here is the same test, but now using `mat-slide-toggle input` as the selector. Everything works properly, albeit I think toggle should emit the change event and this "kind of hack" wouldn't be required. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-test-2vbj7p?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 17):

### your component.html

```
    <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onToggle($event)">Compare</mat-slide-toggle>
```

### In your component you can check

```
    event.checked = true || false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting by css `'form mat-slide-toggle input'` did the trick as mention by [user1902183](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902183/user1902183)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe this'll help other developers that arrive here because of events not firing when testing components which use angular material components in their template.
There are multiple issues opened due to similar problems, and in none of them i find a suggestions for [using Component Harness](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses), which was introduced in Angular 9.

This is a much easier, concise, readable way to perform testing on angular material elements.